# Facing Flickering issue in multiselect checkbox dropdown when try to implement react syncfusion query builder component inside MUI Drawer component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, query-builder, syncfusion

**I'm trying to implement the React Syncfusion query builder inside the MUI drawer.** While implementing this, I'm facing a **flickering issue** with the multiselect checkbox for the IN operator.

If I implement the query builder component outside the MUI drawer component, it works fine without any flickering.

I think it might be because of the conflict between two kinds of popups (MUI drawer and multiselect dropdown). I need to implement the syncfusion query builder component's multiselect checkbox dropdown without any flickering inside the MUI drawer.

**Query Builder - Child**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { QueryBuilderComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-querybuilder";
import { complexData } from "./QueryBuilderJSON";
import { Slider } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-inputs";
import { getComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-base";

import { DropDownList, MultiSelect } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns";

let qryBldrObj;

export default function QueryBuilderComplexDataBinding() {
  const [queryJson, setQueryJson] = useState();
  let elem;
  let dropDownObj;
  let multiSelectObj;
  let inOperators = ["in", "notin"];

  let fieldMode = "DropdownTree";
  let separator = ".";
  let columns = [
    {
      field: "Primary",
      label: "Primary",
      columns: [
        { field: "age", label: "Age", type: "number" },
        {
          field: "gender",
          label: "Gender",
          type: "boolean",
          values: ["Male", "Female", "Others"],
        },
        { field: "profession", label: "Profession", type: "string" },
      ],
    },
    {
      field: "Amount",
      label: "Amount",
      columns: [
        {
          field: "amount",
          label: "Amount",
          type: "number",
          //template to declare it is a range slider
          template: {
            create: () => {
              elem = document.createElement("div");
              elem.setAttribute("class", "ticks_slider");
              return elem;
            },
            destroy: (args) => {
              getComponent(
                document.getElementById(args.elementId),
                "slider"
              ).destroy();
            },
            write: (args) => {
              let slider = new Slider({
                value: !args.values ? 0 : args.values,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                type: "MinRange",
                tooltip: {
                  isVisible: true,
                  placement: "Before",
                  showOn: "Hover",
                },
                change: (e) => {
                  if (qryBldrObj) {
                    qryBldrObj.notifyChange(e.value, args.elements);
                  }
                },
              });
              slider.appendTo("#" + args.elements.id);
            },
          },
          operators: [
            { key: "Equal", value: "equal" },
            { key: "Not equal", value: "notequal" },
            { key: "Greater than", value: "greaterthan" },
            { key: "Less than", value: "lessthan" },
            { key: "Less than or equal", value: "lessthanorequal" },
            {
              key: "Greater than or equal",
              value: "greaterthanorequal",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      field: "PaymentMode",
      label: "Payment Mode",
      operators: [
        { key: "Equal", value: "equal" },
        { key: "Not Equal", value: "notequal" },
        { key: "In", value: "in" },
        { key: "Not In", value: "notin" },
      ],
      template: {
        create: () => {
          debugger;
          elem = document.createElement("input");
          elem.setAttribute("type", "text");
          return elem;
        },
        destroy: (args) => {
          debugger;
          multiSelectObj = getComponent(
            document.getElementById(args.elementId),
            "multiselect"
          );
          if (multiSelectObj) {
            multiSelectObj.destroy();
          }
          dropDownObj = getComponent(
            document.getElementById(args.elementId),
            "dropdownlist"
          );
          if (dropDownObj) {
            dropDownObj.destroy();
          }
        },
        write: (args) => {
          debugger;
          const ds = [
            "Cash",
            "Debit Card",
            "Credit Card",
            "Net Banking",
            "Wallet",
          ];
          //returns the position of the first occurrence of a value in a string.
          //The indexOf() method returns -1 if the value is not found
          if (inOperators.indexOf(args.operator) > -1) {
            multiSelectObj = new MultiSelect({
              change: (e) => {
                debugger;
                if (qryBldrObj) {
                  qryBldrObj.notifyChange(e.value, e.element);
                }
              },
              dataSource: ds,
              mode: "CheckBox",
              placeholder: "Select Transaction",
              value: args.values,
              selectAllText: "Select All",
              unSelectAllText: "unSelect All",
              showSelectAll: true,
            });
            multiSelectObj.appendTo("#" + args.elements.id);
          } else {
            dropDownObj = new DropDownList({
              change: (e) => {
                if (qryBldrObj) {
                  qryBldrObj.notifyChange(e.itemData.value, e.element);
                }
              },
              dataSource: ds,
              value: args.values ? args.values : ds[0],
            });
            dropDownObj.appendTo("#" + args.elements.id);
          }
        },
      },
      type: "string",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <QueryBuilderComponent
      dataSource={complexData}
      columns={columns}
      //rule={importRules}
      change={fnGetRule}
      fieldMode={fieldMode}
      separator={separator}
      ref={(scope) => {
        qryBldrObj = scope;
      }}
    ></QueryBuilderComponent>
  );
}
```

**Drawer - Parent**

```html
<Box key="right">
    <Drawer anchor="right" open={props.open}>
        <div>
            <QueryBuilderComplexDataBinding />
        </div>
    </Drawer>
</Box>
```

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The dropdown div adds and gone out immediatly.. It's only happening while using it inside MUI drawer component.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ModalProps property to the drawer shown below.

```
<Drawer
  anchor="right"
  width={1000}
  open
  ModalProps={{ disableEnforceFocus: true }}
>
  <QueryBuilderComplexDataBinding /> 
</Drawer>
```

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-libed6-xifymn?file=QueryBuilder.js,demo.tsx